# No static resources (js and html) are loading in a Spring Rest and AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, spring

Below is the structure of my resources folder with JS files, which are not loading and I get a 404 error if I start the application

[image]

Below are the files

1) test-servlet.xml (dispatcher servlet)

```
<beans>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <!-- <mvc:view-controller path="/*" view-name="index"/> -->
    <!--  <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/js" /> -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.org.simpro"/>
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.org.simpro"></jpa:repositories>
    <bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    </bean>

    <bean id="HelloWorldRestController" class="com.org.simpro.controller.HelloWorldRestController">
        <property name="userService" ref="userServiceImpl"></property>
    </bean> 

    <bean id= "userServiceImpl" class="com.org.simpro.service.UserServiceImpl">
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"/>
        <property name="username" value="HR"/>
        <property name="password" value="hr"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"></property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.org.simpro.model" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</prop>
                <!-- 
                <prop key="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action">none</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.ejb.use_class_enhancer">true</prop>

                //jpa hibernate properties
                hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
                hibernate.format_sql=true
                hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
                hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
                hibernate.show_sql=false
                -->
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>   
            </props>
        </property> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <import resource="security-context.xml"/> 
</beans>
```

2) web.xml

```
<web-app>
     <filter>
         <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
         <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
     </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
         <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
         <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>  

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
         <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
         </servlet-class>
         <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
     </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping> 

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/test-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener> 

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your spring servlet is mapped to `/`. That means that it is used for **all** paths in your webapp. So you need to [configure Spring to serve static resources](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-static-resources).